# Как выполнить большой цикл на сайте без ошибки 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

Имеем asp.net mvc с методом, в котором выполняется очень долгий цикл. Обращаемся к этому методу, он начинает выполняться, а затем принудительно выбрасывается сервером с ошибкой таймаута.

Пробовал сделать через Task.Run, не помогло, часть результатов сохранилась, а часть не успела.

Сайт деплоится в Azure.

Comment: То есть вы хотите заставить юзера ждать две минуты до тех пор, пока сайт откликнется?

Comment: @VladD формирование документа - процесс не скоротечный, придется.

Comment: Ну, я бы отдал вначале заглушку, и связался через какой-нибудь вебсокет, чтобы обновлять прогресс и показать готовый документ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Длительные операции так или иначе нужно выполнять в фоне. ASP.NET начиная с 4.5.2 имеет https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx

У Azure есть http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx

Если всё же это не подходит, надо копать в сторону работы с IRegisteredObject. Он гарантирует нормальное завершение, можно будет отследить, когда сам IIS захочет прибить задачу, по моему опыту не дает фоновым задачам работать более 90 секунд. В случае использования IRegisteredObject можно отследить момент прибития задачи.

P.S. IIS при этом может и сам завершиться когда захочет, так что без прикрытия тылов с помощью IRegisteredObject или использования https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx нельзя вообще запускать длительные задачи, которые гарантированно должны правильно завершиться.

Comment: С выносом в фоновый поток задача выполняется, но почему-то не всегда корректно. Думаю WebJob тут должен помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно установить таймаут для действия контроллера, по дефолту 110 сек кажется.

Через web.config: 
тег [location на msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
<configuration>
    <location path="ControllerName/ActionName">
        <system.web>
            <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000"/>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Из кода

```
HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = 1000;
```

Comment: не сработало, все равно 2 минуты и выкидывает

Comment: Внёс дополнения в ответ

Comment: `location` будет элементом второго уровня в конфиге, внутри дефолтного `configuration`

Comment: `"ControllerName/ActionName"` правильно указаны?

Comment: указал правильно, в дебаге показывает, что таймаут стал 1000, но при деплое в Azure все равно 2 минуты и ошибка

Comment: А если вторым методом выставить таймаут? Деплоится с тем же конфигом или он затирается?

Comment: проверил оба варианта, значение переменной меняется, но эффекта нет, конфиг обновляется

Comment: Можно выложить сигнатуру метода со всеми атрибутами?

Comment: Хм, так он у меня ничего не принимает. public async Task<ActionResult> Resourcecache()

Comment: Действительно с азуром не просто всё.    Load balancer всегда сам выставляет таймаут и это никак не изменить, можно завязаться на ajax запросы и смотреть с клиента выполнен ли запрос на сервере периодически, как советует парень в этой теме https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184752/set-timeout-for-controller-action

Comment: очень геморный вариант, проще цикл на итерации по минуте разделить))

Comment: На мой взгляд хуже, когда не будет гарантии выполнения метода, из-за возможности таймаута операции

Answer (score 0):

Длительные операции в Asp.Net не очень приветствуются и очень часто приводят не совсем к желаемым операциям. Можно воспользоваться WebJobs если сайт исключительно на Azure. А еще можно посмотреть в сторону [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) - решение не зависимое от платформы.